# How to use gmail within emacs on windows 7

Tags: emacs, gmail

there is lot of related question but I can't figured out...
link to emacs wiki ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll need specifics of what Emacs mail client you're using. There's [Gnus](http://www.gnus.org/), [VM](http://launchpad.net/vm) and [wanderlust](http://www.gohome.org/wl/) as far as I know.

Gmail has POP and IMAP services which you can (and must if you want to use them) enable. Once you do this, you can fetch your email directly using one of the above clients.

However, since Emacs is single threaded, your editor will "freeze" when it actually downloads email so I recommend and use [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/) to download my mail into a local spool file and then have Gnus pick up the email from there. It's a lot quicker and works just as well.

Answer (score 3):

I am using emacs on 4 different machines spanning 4 different OS'es, I can't afford to have my mail on one machine and I can't spend my time configuring pop3 or imap on every machine I happen to have to work on. Webmail is my friend and it could be your friend too, with the right browser extensions.

The [edit-server extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh) or [It's all Text extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) are both two great alternatives to having emacs or fetchmail download huge quantities of mail to a machine you don't want the mail on.

Simply put; let gmail keep the mail where it is and edit new mails (or any other text area) in emacs.

..but, that wasn't exactly what you were asking about. (get the extensions anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to read email from your gmail account in emacs, you can use any POP3 or IMAP-capable email client to access your gmail account (assuming you have POP3 or IMAP access enabled).

Typical clients would include VM or Wanderlust and I'm sure there are a few more out there.